# Find $J: S^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, if given $I:S^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, s.t. $I(\vec{a})=\int_{S^2}\vec{n}\cdot\vec{a} J(\vec{n}) ds$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, physics, inverse-problems

I thought of the following problem, when we were discussing radiation intensity in an astrophysics lecture.
Suppose $\mathbb{R}^3$ is filled with uniform radiation, i.e. there is a function $J:S^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, so that at any point in $\mathbb{R}$ the amount of radiation in direction $\vec{n}$ is $J(\vec{n})$.
If we put a unit area with normal vector $\vec{a}$ into space, we can calculate the flux $I$ through it by $I(\vec{a})=\int_{S^2}\vec{n}\cdot\vec{a} J(\vec{n}) ds
= \int_{S^2}\cos(\sphericalangle(\vec{n},\vec{a})) J(\vec{n}) ds $.

Under what conditions and how is it possible to do the inverse, i.e. calculate $J$ given $I$?

Of course there will be several $J$'s for an $I$, since many $J$'s lead to the same $I$. This leads to the next question: 'How big' are the classes of $J$'s that correspond to an $I$?

For example, when calculating the flux, the symmetric part of $J$ does not contribute anything.
I think, this problem is analogous to calculating the deconvolution of a function convoluted around the cosine, just on a sphere instead of the real line, and the distance between two points on the sphere is the angle of their position vector.

Answer (score 2):

My text is too long for a comment so I put it here:
I'm not sure if I completely understand your notations. What I understand is that if I know a certain function $J:S^2\rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ like $(\phi,\theta)\mapsto \theta^2$, in spherical coordinates (with $r=1$), and a "unit area" (I think you mean something like a square or a disk having surface $=1$ and perpendicular to a vector of length $1$ named $\vec{a}$) then I can calulate $I(\vec{a})$. The location of the center of this surface object not being important (I think this is why the radiation is called uniform), lets take a square that is perpendicular to the $y$-axis then what would be the value of $I(\vec{a})$?

Comment: It would vanish, because it's symmetric in $\phi$ (easy to picture physically why: the radiation coming in from behind compensates the part from the front). If you pick $\vec{a}$ as the z-axis you get $\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}sin(\theta)\theta^2 sin(\theta)=\pi^2-4$, where the last $\sin\theta$ is the cosine of the angle between $\vec{n}$ and the z axis.

Comment: Otherwise, it seems, that you understood the problem.

Comment: Not quite, I don't see any differentials in the formula ($\mathrm{d}\phi,\mathrm{d}\theta$). And where does $\pi^2$ comes from?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write down the differentials. The $\pi^2-4$ is just the value of the integral, as computed by wolframalpha. I think  I forgot to multiply for $2\pi$ from the $d\phi$ integral, so it should be $2\pi^3-8\pi$.

Comment: Is it possible to write the complete integral for a given function $J(\phi,\theta)$ and a given normal $a=(\phi',\theta')$? PS: the dot product is given as $(\cos(\theta)\cos(\theta') + \cos(\phi-\phi')\sin(\theta)\sin(\theta'))$

Comment: An idea would be to see what $I$ gives when $J$ takes the form of several spherical harmonics, (or any other basis for the Hilbert space of square integrable functions on $S^2$) and then to reverse engineer it.

Comment: I thought about the spherical harmonics idea, but then solving the anologous proplem in one dimension on the circle (which is deconvoluting a function convoluted around cosine) with the fourier basis looks too difficult.

Comment: Sory, that was a stupid comment. I will try your idea.

Comment: I'm very interested in the result, and I'll make it my meditation subject for the evening :)

Comment: Could it be that $I(\phi',\theta')=\iint J(\phi,\theta)(\cos(\theta)\cos(\theta') + \cos(\phi-\phi')\sin(\theta)\sin(\theta'))\sin(\theta)\mathrm{d}\theta\mathrm{d}\phi$

Answer (score 2):

Following Nimda's hint, $J$ can be decomposed into spherical harmonics $Y_l^m$. Therefore, it is useful to look at the flux function $I_{Y_l^m}$ corresponding to the $J=Y_l^m$ for all possible $l$,$m$. It is useful to use the addition theorem for spherical harmonics: $P_l(cos(\gamma)=\frac{4\pi}{2l+1}\sum_{m=-l}^{l}Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)Y_l^{m*}(\theta',\phi')$, where $\gamma$ is the angle between the points $(\theta,\phi)$ and $(\theta',\phi')$. Because, $P_1(x)=x$, this means $\vec{n}\cdot\vec{a}=\frac{4\pi}{3}\sum_{m=-1}^{1}Y_1^m(\theta,\phi)Y_1^{m}(\theta',\phi')^*$.
Hence, we get
$$
I_{Y_l^m} = \int_{S^2} \frac{4\pi}{3}\sum_{m'=-1}^{1}Y_1^{m'}(\theta,\phi)Y_1^{m'}(\theta',\phi')^*Y_l^{m}(\theta',\phi')
$$
This is equal to $\frac{4\pi}{3} Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)$ if $l=1$ and $0$ for other $l$.\
This shows, that only linear combinations of $Y_1^{-1}$, $Y_1^0$ and $Y_1^1$ are possible functions for $I$'s, that have a corresponding $J$. Furthermore, if we are given $I$ as a decomposition into spherical harmonics, $I(\theta,\phi)=\sum_{m=-1}^1 b_m Y_1^m(\theta,\phi)$, then 
$$J(\theta,\phi)=\sum_{m=-1}^1 b_m\frac{3}{4\pi} Y_1^m(\theta,\phi) + \sum_{1\neq l=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=-1}^1 c_{l,m}Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)$$
, where $c_{l,m}$ are arbitrary coefficients.