# Rerformulation of a previous question concerning a problem in physics that involves integration of 2-forms over the sphere

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

In this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/944030/find-j-s2-rightarrow-mathbbr-if-given-is2-rightarrow-mathbbr-s-t/944159#944159) the integral proposed in the posting concerns a physical problem that can shortly be described by the following : Let $J$ be a real valued function on the sphere (in fact it is a vector field in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that in the point $t$ takes the value $J(t/||t||)$). Let $s\in S^2$(seen as a direction in the physical model)  and let $\mathrm{d}\sigma$ be a 2-form at this point then $\delta(s,t)J(t)\mathrm{d}\sigma$ represents the flux of $J$ through this surface element (here $\delta$ is the $\cos$ of the angle between $s$ and $t$). Then the total flux through the origin can be described by the integral: $$I(s)=\iint_{S^2}\delta(s,t)J(t)\mathrm{d}\sigma$$ Where $s,t \in S^2$, $J$ and $I$, real valued functions on a sphere, $\delta(s,t)$ the dot product $s.t$, and $\mathrm{d}\sigma$ the standard 2-form on the sphere. The integral can be seen as a linear operator on a Hilbert space of functions $J$ that are sufficiently integrable. Now the first question that came to my mind was: Can this operator be diagonalized or otherwise given a simplified form?

Comment: That certainly is a more descriptive title.

Comment: @amcalde I was a bit reluctant to let the physical details in as that would create the impression to be off topic in a math forum, but I intrinsically feel that this is a math problem and not a physics problem.

Comment: Apparently there is a paper about this or at least something similar. 

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0885064X08000174

They break the thing down using spherical harmonics. And discuss conditions for decaying eigenvalues. etc. Not sure if it helps.

Comment: In the original posting we discussed using spherical harmonics and it seems to be working, but I was just interested if there were some nice properties of this operator.

Comment: Constant vector fields like $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ is obviously eigenvectors of this operator, with eigenvalues of constant functions. Since $\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\}$ is orthonormal, to compute the image of an arbitrary vector field reduces to compute three integrals of their components.